# Can the verb "watch" be used with that-clause?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs

Can the verb "watch" be used with that-clause when it has the meaning 'to look at'?

Are the following statements correct?

> We watched the government and business community cope with the ongoing crisis.
>
> We watched that the government and business community cope with the ongoing crisis.

Comment: It can, but bear in mind that your _watching_ example is not a sentence, but a subordinate non-finite clause that would normally be part of a sentence.

Comment: @BillJ I've just edited the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Interesting. I know that the answer is "no", but I couldn't explain why.

Comment: Your revision is not acceptable, at least not where "watch" means "look at". "Watch" + _that_ clauses occur readily in examples like "You watch that you don't get glue on your fingers" where "watch" has the sense of "be careful".

Comment: @BillJ But can you explain to the OP WHY their two sentences have different meanings? If you change it to "I see that the government is coping...", the word "that" is completely optional. How come?

Comment: "Watch" is transitive in the first example with "the government ..." as direct object. All perfectly normal. But I don't think "watch" with the sense "look at" licenses (permits) a content clause complement. It could, however, be used with the sense "ensure", though some may consider that similar to the "be careful" sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/watch), the verb **watch** has two meanings.

In your original sentence, the meaning is LOOK AT, with the form **+ object + infinitive-without-to**: the object is **the government and business community** and the infitive-without-to is **cope**.

The **LOOK AT** meaning also supports the **-ing verb** form or a **question word**:

> We watched the government and business community **coping** with the ongoing crisis.
>   We watched **how** the government and business community **copes** with the ongoing crisis.

The **LOOK AT** meaning of **watch** does not support a that-clause: the **BE CAREFUL** meaning does, so you can say something like this:

> Watch **that** you don't get paint on the carpet.

Note that, when you use a that-clause, the verb is not an infinitive: it must take the appropriate verb tense for the clause, for example simple present. Here's how it works with **hope**, which can use a that-clause:

> I **hope** that the government and business community **copes** with the ongoing crisis.

Answer (score 0):

No.   "To watch" means something more specific than "to look at".   It means to observe over a period of time, to observe a process.   You can look at a book as easily as you can look at a movie, but you cannot watch a book in the same sense that you can watch a movie.

> We watched the government and business community cope with the ongoing crisis.

This is a perfectly ordinary sentence.   We can divide its one clause into four constituents: a subject, a finite verb, a direct object and an object complement.   This sense of the verb "to watch" does license bare infinitive object complements, and the phrase "[to] cope with the ongoing crisis" is a suitable infinitive phrase.   As modified by its complement, this direct object represents a process with a duration.   It makes sense as the object of the verb "watched".

> We watched that the government and business community cope with the ongoing crisis.

There is something wrong with this sentence.   It has a perfectly ordinary (and somewhat more complicated) structure, but it doesn't quite make sense.   At least, it doesn't make the kind of sense that you intend.

The intended sense of the verb "to watch" does not require an object complement.   It does require a direct object.   We have a direct object in the subordinate clause "that the government and business community cope with the ongoing crisis".   In this case, "cope" must be finite.   The "that" introduces a complete clause and allows that clause to represent a *fact*.

And there's the problem.   A fact, like a book, isn't a process -- even when the fact is *that a process occurs*.   The fact itself lacks an inherent duration.   It simply exists.   We cannot watch a fact in the same sense that we can watch a movie.

For this sentence to make sense, we would need to find some sense of the verb "to watch" that licenses a different semantic role.   These senses can be found, such as the religious sense of *to hold vigil* or *to pray throughout the night* which can license a purpose rather than a process.

Alternately, we can replace "watched" with a verb that licenses a more appropriate semantic role, one that does not require an inherent duration.   Verbs like "saw", "observed" and "noticed" have fewer semantic restrictions regarding their direct objects.